# Code signing with osslsigncode - Publisher Unknown

Tags: openssl, nsis, code-signing, signtool

I encountered a bit peculiar behavior when trying to automate compilation and signing of particular NSIS-based binary. Namely, `makensis` is run under `wine` to compile the executable, and afterwards the `osslsigncode` is used to sign the binary.

Executable seems to be built fine, as it works on Windows systems, however there's an issue (in the lack of better word) with the signing. As the code signing certificate is in PKCS#12 format, the command used is as suggested [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osslsigncode/files/osslsigncode/):

`osslsigncode sign -pkcs12 <pkcs12-file> -pass <pkcs12-password> \
        -n "Your Application" -i http://www.yourwebsite.com/ \
        -in yourapp.exe -out yourapp-signed.exe`

I get "Succeeded" message from osslsigncode, as if the signing went OK, however when the binary is run on Windows (Win 7 in this case), UAC says:

Publisher: **Unknown**

The strange thing is that when I opened the extracted cert from original `.p12` file, to view it's info, Windows was afterwards able to recognize the publisher and the digital signature, as if it somehow became aware of the certification path...?

Any advice would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**
osslsigncode versions used: 1.5.2 and 1.7.1

**EDIT 2**
For the sake of comparison, I tried signing with `SignTool`, and apparently it works without any problem. So this looks like cert + `osslsigncode` issue, but I can't tell what is it exactly.

I also tried `osslsigncode` on the exact same EXE with another cert, and to make matters more interesting, it worked... (I noticed certification paths differ for the 2 certs).

Some cert details:

1) *non-working cert*
version: V3
public key: RSA 2048 bits
signature hash algorithm: sha1
signature algorithm: sha1RSA
certification path: USERTrust -> Comodo Code Signing CA 2 -> NonWorkingCert

2) *working cert*
version: V3
public key: RSA 2048 bits
signature hash algorithm: sha1
signature algorithm: sha1RSA
certification path: USERTrust -> UTN-UserFirst-Object -> Comodo Code Signing CA 2 -> WorkingCert

Comment: Strange. I'm having this same issue years later. Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 6):

This cost me several hours of head-scratching, but I think I understand now.

- Windows has its internal database of trusted certificates. These include root certificates (installed & updated by Windows) and additional intermediate CA certs which it has seen at various times (signed by a root cert or some other trusted cert).
- When Windows/UAC checks an executable signature at launch, it looks in the local database for a trusted certificate which has signed the root of the certificates embedded in the executable signature.
- If Windows can't find a trusted signing certificate (maybe because the embedded cert is signed with an intermediate cert, not a root cert, and the intermediate cert is not in the local database), it leads to Unknown Publisher.
- If you view the "Digital Signatures" tab of the executable Properties, Windows goes one step further and tries automatically to download and install any valid intermediate certs which are trusted by one of its local certs. Once this intermediate cert has been added to Windows' local certificate storage, the signature check at executable launch will also start passing (ie correct Publisher is shown). ([This MSDN answer explains the logic, although the root cause they describe - root cert not yet updated - is different.)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/8fc866f9-7c56-4895-85d5-f63d09a73b6f/dpinstexe-does-not-recognize-signature-immediately?forum=wdk)

The solution is to pass the intermediate cert to `osslsigncode` along with the main cert. ([H/T to Tor Project for confirming this](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/17870#comment:6).)

- Find the correct intermediate CA cert. Can be done via `openssl x509 -text -in cert.pem` and then look for "Authority Information Access
  -> "CA Issuers" URI. Certificate identifiers (serial numbers, etc) can also be found in Windows under the "Digital Certificates" tab -> "View Certificate" -> "Certification Path".

  (Tip: Don't always trust the CA's support pages to have correct info for which intermediate cert to download, I wasted a lot of time after downloading the wrong intermediate certs from a CA's web page.)
- Convert all certs to PEM format if necessary with `openssl x509 -in my_intermediate_ca.crt -inform der -outform pem -out my_intermediate_ca.pem` or similar.
- Put the full CA chain into one PEM file, with the code signing cert first: `cat mycert.pem my_intermediate_ca.pem > certchain.pem`

  (If code signing cert is not first in the chain, Windows sees an invalid signature which is "signed" by the intermediate cert.)
- Run `osslsigncode -certs certchain.pem ...`

  (Note: I also passed `-h sha256` & `-ts http://timestamp.digicert.com` although I think everything will work with other combinations of options, also.)

Comment: I thought this was common knowledge, that UAC had this issue. Really on the Windows the correct method would be to consult `signtool verify` or the respective PowerShell cmdlet. Both should go through `WinVerifyTrust` and also trigger the lookup of any missing pieces in the certificate chain.